# combobox validation

Tags: arrays, combobox, vb6

I have 6 comboboxes on one form - they are in an array. They are called cboClient(0) thru cboClient(5). What I'm trying to do here is validate that there is a value so something along the lines of

```
if cboclient(0)<>"" and not isnull(cboClient(0)) then
   'Do this
End if
```

Each cbo gets populated with the same list of items. My goal is to make sure that user CAN'T make the same selection in more than 1 cbo. Basically if they choose item 1 in cboClient(0), that item cannot be selected in any other cbo.

I'm trying to find a way so that I can do this in as few lines as possible, I could potentially do it like this..but it would be extremely long as I have to verify each cbo against the others

```
if cboClient(0).text <> cboClient(1).text then
    msgbox "OK"
Else
    msgbox "Please choose again"
End if
```

I'm trying to somehow write it possibly in a loop? to verify the .text in each cbo and make sure no two identical selection were made. Any idea?

EDIT:
I have 6 cbo's - each one gets populated with the same data (say data numbers 1 through 10). If user selects "1" in cboClient(0), they can't select this in another cbo. I don't necessarily want to hide it from them - but once they click SAVE - I want to have a function in place to run through the CBO's and check if they've selected the same item more than once - if they have, I want to give them a MsgBox saying "Fix your selection, you cannot have two items"

EDIT 2:

Maybe do two loops - one within another...

```
dim a as integer
dim b as integer

for a = 0 to 5
   for b = 1 to 5
       if cboClient(a).text <> cboclient(b).text then
          'keep going
       else
           MsgBox "you have made the same selection"
       End if
   next b
next a
```

Something like that?

Comment: The tag and title VB.NET has to be a lie. There are no control arrays in VB.NET. Anyway, what I would do would be *remove* the item from all of the other comboboxes once it has been selected in one. That way, the user can't accidentally select it. Much friendlier UI than a message box. Yes, you can use a loop. It's not clear what your actual problem is.

Comment: My apologies for Tag. I have 6 cbo's - each one gets populated with the same data (say data numbers 1 through 10). If user selects "1" in cboClient(0), they can't select this in another cbo. I don't necessarily want to hide it from them - but once they click SAVE - I want to have a function in place to run through the CBO's and check if they've selected the same item more than once - if they have, I want to give them a MsgBox saying "Fix your selection, you cannot have two items"

Comment: It sounds like a multiselect listbox would be more appropriate

Comment: Yes, but this is already in place - it's a fully function application and I'm just trying to find an easy way to do this. Hopefully with a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
For i = 0 To 5
    For j = 0 To 5
        If i <> j And cboClient(i).Text = cboClient(j).Text Then
            MsgBox "You must choose diffirent values, Please choose again"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: thanks! I was just thinking the same thing - works great I'm just not going to loop through all the values but have the MSGBOX the first time it hits a duplicate selection.

Comment: Glad to hear that! I change code to show message the first time it hits a duplicate selection! Thank you too :)